# Inconsistency between Ti and Appc CLI

Tags: titanium, command-line-interface, appcelerator

I have been creating some node npm scripts  to help with creating Titanium projects for both Titanium  and Appcelerator (the difference is that the Appc projects are registered in your platform account).

I have tried both a standard `ti create`  and running an `appc ti create`  as well as `appc new`  and found a few inconsistencies in how the CLI handles the arguments passed in.

using the Ti CLI
-d seems to be the directory in which your project directory is created, but using appc CLI this is the actual project directory. So for example in Ti for  my test project created with Ti CLI

```
-n test -d /User/fred/projects
```

but for the appc CLI

```
-n test -d /User/fred/projects/test
```

Also for the appc CLI there seems be no way of generate a **Classic** project, it seems determined to create an **Alloy** project, like it or not.

My question/query is is this all correct or is there something I am missing and is there any way of getting the appc CLI to create a classic project rather than an Alloy one ?

appc CLI version: 6.2.2
ti CLI version: 5.0.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use --classic flag to create classic project>

Check this doc and read details of **Create a Titanium Project** section

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Tasks-section-src-43306725_AppceleratorCLITasks-BuildMobileApplications

Comment: How did I miss that?  - thanks works a treat. Just need to get the -d option aligned now :-)